# Cannot read Excel file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I was given an Excel file from a coworker who has, I think, protected it because it contains PII data.  However, I can open it without a problem using Excel, but when I try to open it within my ASP.NET app I am told that I don't have permission and should contact the owner or system administrator.

Simple view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>File:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="displaybutton" style="font-size:x-small;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
 }
```

Is there anyway to fix this?[image]

Comment: Fix what? You didn't post any relevant code, only a form with an upload field

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, when I select the file in the view I get that message so posting any code is useless.

Comment: Make sure you have at-least read permission on that file in the directory.

Comment: @Dean.DePue you mean you can't even read the file? You *can't* read a file if the creator restricted permissions. It has nothing to do with coding. Can you open it by double-clicking?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yes, that is what I mean.  Yes, I can open the file no problem.  I even changed the permissions to allow full control for everyone and I still get the error.

Comment: What error? An OS error, a yellow screen, an exception, a browser dialog box? Client or server-side? People can't help if you don't give any details. What you posted is just a client-side form.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I've edited the question showing the error I see when I simply select an try to open the file with the file dialog